# How do I prevent SOLR allowing a blank query

Tags: mysql, solr

I installed Apache SOLR on my own server. It's integrated into Wordpress in that I can index my WP posts as searchable pages in SOLR.

My question is simple, yet surprisingly hard to locate an answer for. I am trying to figure out how to prevent a user from being able to perform a blank search query, when searching my website?

Currently, a user can enter nothing in the search form field, just hit enter, and effectively search nothing. This causes the search results to return my entire indexed pages.

I created a Analyzer requiring a minimum of 3 characters to be entered. The problem is it restricted 1, and 2 characters, but still allow "0".

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the behavior you describe is not that zero is being used as a value in the `WHERE` clause of the underlying query, but rather that the `WHERE` clause itself is being dropped when you enter zero.  I suspect you will need a Solr solution to handle this.

Comment: Disabling empty searches should probably be fixed in the plugin talking to Solr, as well as fixing the corresponding UI for the template with the search box.

Comment: Yea that's the confusing part. There's all kinds configuration and schema files in the actual SOLR installation on my server. Then there's even more configuration files (i.e. SolrConf.xml, Schema.xml) in the 3rd party WPSOLR plug im using.

Comment: So pinpointing where the issue is coming from (solr installation or plug-in) is proving to be a chore